# WPF lines and polylines events for a 2D Editor

Tags: wpf, graphics, editor, 2d, line

i want to create a 2d-editor like application in WPF an i need to know how to do this:

1. How can intercept the event when i click on a Line or Polyline?
2. How can detect the end / beginning of a line and show a small dot or small box in the end or the beginning of the line. Is there a way to raise an event if i get close of end or the beginning of the line?
3. How can i create a panning and zooming functionality? How can i control the canvas for that functionality?
4. How can i maintain the aspect ratio between X and Y and the scale. I mean if i have a horizontal line of length 5 and a vertical line of length 5, what do i have to do to both lines look the same length visually?

Thanks for your answers.
Eduardo

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much, but the ideas that came to my mind are as below, correct me if anything wrong.

- Using Hit-Testing [[Ref]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx) or Pre-defined extendable Shapes [[Ref]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx), which already have common Input events (like `MouseEnter`, `MouseLeave`, ...)
- For showing a small dot, u can use [Adorners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx). Every line a has end and start point, u can just get it's value and adjust your visual (small dot) for them. Yes, `Adorner` can help u, they are just like any other `UIElement`, so commons events like `MouseEnter`, `MouseLeave`, ... are there.
- For panning and zooming, u can use the code from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/swordfishcharts.aspx) or [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/zoomandpancontrol.aspx) or [here](http://deepzoom.codeplex.com/)
- The lines will be visually same. Just draw them using Shapes (link above).